# Absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\sigma$ be an element in the absolute Galois group of the $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$. We denote the algebraic closure by $\mathbb{A}_p$. If we have for any algebraic integers $x\in\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_p},\sigma(x)-x\in(p)\subseteq\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_p}$. Then to show is $\sigma$ is the identity.

I want to prove $\sigma(x)=x$ for any algebraic integers. It can be reduced to show that Galois conjugates can not be congruent mod $(p)$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Also, you meant "fix" by the restriction on the maximal ideal is identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Given $\sigma\in Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p/\Bbb{Q}_p)$ such that $\forall x\in O_{\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p}^\times, v(x-\sigma(x)) \ge v(p)=1$. $\tag{1}$

Let $a\in p\, O_{\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p}$, for every $k$
$$(1+a)^{p^k}=\sum_{m=0}^{p^k}{p^k\choose m} a^m\equiv 1\bmod p^k \tag{2}$$

Assume $v(x)=0,x\ne \sigma(x)$ then  $v((\frac{x}{\sigma(x)})^{1/p^k}-1)=v(x^{1/p^k}-\sigma(x^{1/p^k}))> 0$, let $$r = \inf_k v( x^{1/p^k}-\sigma(x^{1/p^k}))$$

- If $r<1$ then we have a contradiction with $(1)$.
- Thus $r \ge 1$ and for all $k$ we have $v( (\frac{x}{\sigma(x)})^{1/p^k}-1)\ge 1$,

  $(2)$ implies that for all $k$, $v( \frac{x}{\sigma(x)}-1)\ge k$, letting $k\to \infty$ we get $v( \frac{x}{\sigma(x)}-1)=\infty$ ie. $$x=\sigma(x)$$

And hence $\sigma$ is the identity.

Comment: I have a question: if we consider $X^2-p$ which has two roots $\pm\sqrt{p}$. Let $\sigma$ be the automorphism permute the two roots. Now reduction mod $p$, we get $X^2$, which means two roots reduced to 0. But then $\sigma(\sqrt{p})\equiv\sqrt{p}\equiv0$.

Comment: $\equiv 0$ modulo what ? As you see $\bmod p$ (for $p$ odd) it is untrue

Comment: Yes, I meant mod $p$. $(X-\sqrt{p})(X+\sqrt{p})=X^2-p$. By mod $p$, we have $(X-[\sqrt{p}])(X+[\sqrt{p}])=X^2$ in $\kappa[X]$. $\kappa$ is a field, so $[\sqrt{p}]=0$, i.e., $\sqrt{p}\equiv0$ mod $p$. I also think it is weird.

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}}/(p)$ is **not a field**. That $X^2-p$ is monic and $ \equiv X^2 \bmod p$ and that its splitting field is $K=\Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/2})$ imply that its roots are $\equiv 0 \bmod (\pi_K)$ where $(\pi_K)= p^{1/2} O_K$ is the unique prime ideal of $O_K$ containing $p$.

Comment: I see. Do I understand correctly: let $K$ be the finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. $\mathcal{O}_K$ is local but whose maximal ideal is not $p\mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: Yes, a finite extension $K/\Bbb{Q}_p$ is uniquely defined by an uniformizer $\pi_K$ (generating the maximal ideal of $O_K$) and the size of the residue field $O_K/(\pi_K)=\Bbb{F}_{p^f}$, then $O_K=\Bbb{Z}_p[\zeta_{p^f-1}][[\pi_K]]=\Bbb{Z}_p[\zeta_{p^f-1},\pi_K]$. When we can take $\pi_K=p$ then the extension is said unramified and it is much easier. All the difficulty comes from that it is not always the case.

Comment: I was trying to understand the proof. Is it enough to prove only on the units?

Comment: Sure one of $x,1+x$ is a unit (= has valuation $0$)

Comment: But is $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}}$ a DVR (even is it local)? It seems that the ring is quite big.

Comment: The $p$-adic valuation extends (in a unique way) to the algebraic closure, but it is of course not discrete (since $v(p^{1/n})=1/n$). That it is not discrete means that the unique maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}}$ is not finitely generated (it is generated by the $p^{1/n}$) in particular it is not principal, it is not a DVR.